# PyQt - slots with parameter

Tags: python, pyqt, slots

Example:

I have three pushbuttons, all makes almost the same.
I want to have only 1 slot-function for all 3 buttons.

```
def slotButtons(nr_button):

  #common part

  if(nr==1):
    #for button 1
  else if(nr==2):
    #for button 2
  else if(nr==3):
    #for button 3

  #common part
```

So I need something like slots with parameter..

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(pushButton1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), slotButtons(1))
QtCore.QObject.connect(pushButton2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), slotButtons(2))
QtCore.QObject.connect(pushButton3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), slotButtons(3))
```

Can Python(pyQt) do something that?

Comment: QtCore.QObject.connect(pushButton1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda : slotButtons(1))

I've tried this, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `connect` needs is any *callable* Python object. Since Python has functions as first-class objects, this is easy to implement with a wrapper function. For simple cases, a `lambda` would do:

```
    self.connect(pyuic4Button, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
            lambda: self.setPath("pyuic4"))
    self.connect(pyrcc4Button, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
            lambda: self.setPath("pyrcc4"))
```

Comment: This the powerfull use of lambda express :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QObject::sender()` function to behave differently for each sender, object, see [QObject documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#sender) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PyQt  but take a look at QSignalMapper documentation, it should be the same. Basically, it allows you to map signals coming from different objects to a slot with a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a member variable to identify the object and do something like the following im sure.

```
def slotButtons(btn):
    if btn.who_are_you == 1:
        # Do some stuff
    elif btn.who_are_you == 2:
        # Do some stuff
    elif btn.who_are_you == 3:
        # Do some stuff

    # Common part
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do :

```
lambda value: self.doStuff(True if value==True else False)
```

Its quite great tool once you figure out how it works.

Edit:
You can also skip doing all the ifs/else...
Just go straight to point... - rough example:

```
btn_01 = lambda: self.doStuff("C://")
btn_02 = lambda: self.doStuff("D://")

def doStuff(self,dir):
     saveFile(dir+"filename.txt")
```